# How to change the parent scope from ng-repeat individual scope - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following scenario

I have a table with n rows. In each row, a `total` column is there. All the values of the row columns are summed and total is populated for a row. At the end, all the row totals are summed to get the `grant total`.

The table rows are generated using `ng-repeat`. This is my logic, when the cell values are changed, the row total will be updated. Row total has the expression `{{ $parent.grant_total = parseInt($parent.grant_total) + num1*num2 }}`, so the total sum will get added up with the `grant total` which is available in the parent scope. But this is not working as expected and I don't know where I am going wrong. I am trying to do this right, the angular way. Find the complete code below

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="grant_total=0"  >
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
  <input type="text" ng-model="num1" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="num2" />
  <input type="text" value="{{ $parent.grant_total = parseInt($parent.grant_total) +(num1*num2) }}"   />
</div>
<input type="text" value={{grant_total}}  />
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', ['$scope','function($scope){
   $scope.items = [1,2,3];
}])
```

Please suggest me a right solution if this is wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qez5rjdk/)**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="i in items">
        Number One:<input type="text" ng-init="num1=0" ng-model="num1" />
        <br>
        Number Two:<input type="text" ng-init="num2=0" ng-model="num2" />
        Total:<input type="text" ng-model="inputs[i-1]" ng-value="inputs[i-1] =(num1*num2);" />
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <input type="text" ng-value="getGrandTotal()" />
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    $scope.inputs = [];

    $scope.getGrandTotal = function () {
        $scope.grantTotal = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.inputs.length; i++) {
            $scope.grantTotal = $scope.grantTotal + $scope.inputs[i];
        }
        return $scope.grantTotal;
    };
});
```

**Description**

- `$scope.inputs` array will stores all the dynamic total values
- Since `$scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4];` and the `ng-repeat="i in items"` and I have put `ng-model="inputs[i-1]"` in such a way so that the four text field model will be like as shown below

  - when `i = 1`, `input[1 - 1]` => `input[0]` => which will be the 1st total text field modal where it will store the first total
  - when `i = 2`, `input[1 - 2]` => `input[1]` => which will be the 2nd total text field modal where it will store the second total
  - when `i = 3`, `input[1 - 3]` => `input[2]` => which will be the 3rd total text field modal where it will store the third total
  - when `i = 4`, `input[1 - 4]` => `input[3]` => which will be the 4th total text field modal where it will store the fourth total
- `$scope.getGrandTotal` function will iterate through `$scope.inputs` array and return the grand total sum.
- `ng-value` is an angular expression, whose value will be bound to the value attribute of the input element.
- `ng-value` is useful for binding dynamically generating values of text-field using ngRepeat

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot. Could you please explain me what ng-value is doing here and also there are many inputs in the page. So $scope.inputs.length may not work.

Comment: I have understood your logic perfectly well. I have another scenario where this grant total value will be updated else where. But the update is not getting reflected in the gran total field. Could you please suggest a solution for it. I have tried $apply, but not working as expected.

Comment: post it as separate SO query

Answer (score 0):

You could use this HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="result = { grant_total: 0 }"  >
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
  <input type="text" ng-model="num1" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="num2" />
  <input type="text" value="{{ result.grant_total = parseInt(result.grant_total) + (num1 * num2) }}"   />
</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="result.grant_total" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as parent" ng-init="parent.grant_total=0">
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="num1"> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="num2" ng-blur="parent.setRunningTotal(num1,num2)"> 
        <input type="text" value="{{ (num1*num2) || 0 }}">
    </div><br>
    <br>

    <input type="text" value="{{parent.runningTotal}}">

</body>
```

and the JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    var self = this;
    this.items = [1,2,3];
    this.runningTotal = 0;
    this.setRunningTotal = function(num1,num2) {
       self.runningTotal += (num1 * num2);
    }
}])
```

I'm using the controller AS syntax which makes it more clear what I'm actually binding to and lets me get away without using `$scope` which can get confusing quickly. Basically it creates an instance of my scope function with the variable defined after the `as` keyword basically it's the same as doing this

```
var myClass = function() {
    this.foo = 'Bar';
}
var fooBar = new myClass();
alert(fooBar.foo);
```

In this way fooBar is an instance of myClass and I can call it wherever I need to.  It works the same way in angular, in my code above parent is an instance of myController and I can access it as deeply as I need to without the use of `$parent` more information including a detailed example of how we can avoid using `$parent` with this method can be found [here](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Working Plunk

http://plnkr.co/edit/2CMfXpfjrzfsD80WFKGX

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But this is not working. I have the exact same problem. The row total is working, but the grant total is populate with the value of last row total. Your snippet have that issue too..

Comment: parseInt will not work in angular expressions. You may need to do it inside controller

Comment: @mohamedrias - Could you please guide me, how to do this inside controller.